# what is the maximum number of records can render in kendo grid client paging

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I want to use kendo grid client paging with large number of records , say 10000 record or above .
what is maximum number can work fine

Comment: Are you asking how many pages a grid can have or how many records can be on each page? Either way I wouldn't worry about that. Either use paging and disable the ajax request on each page click by setting `ServerOperation(false)` [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding#enable-client-data-processing), or use virtual scrolling ([documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/virtualization-remote-data))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Kendo have mentioned any max number of records in there documentation. However, I am sure for 10K records the grid will behave abnormally.

As a solution I would suggest you to hold the data in javascript object and use virtual scrolling feature of kendo grid. It will perform at its best this way.